# Vaadin Ordered and Unordered List

Tags: list, vaadin

can you help me out how to add unordered list and ordered list using vaadin.

While searhing for that i have found `ULElement` but it is an interface, how we can create object for this one

Please help me
Thanks In Advance

Comment: You can simulate it using [Vaadin `Tree`](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created an own Java class:

```
public class HtmlUnorderedList {
    private List<String> listElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListItem(String listItem) {
        listElements.add("<li>" + listItem + "</li>");
    }

    public String getHtml(String classNames) {
        String openingTag = "<ul>";
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(classNames)) {
            openingTag = String.format("<ul class=\"%s\">", classNames);
        }
        return openingTag + StringUtils.join(listElements, "") + "</ul>";
    }
}
```

css:

```
     ul.additionalEvents {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 35px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        color: gray;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
```

Implementation after adding list elements to (HtmlUnorderedList) component:

```
new Label(((HtmlUnorderedList) component).getHtml("additionalEvents"), ContentMode.HTML)
```

Comment: is there any inbuilt classes for lists

Comment: this has the potential for a XSS attack if the `listItem` is not properly protected outside this class.